# Display controller > action as title in dynamically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to display the title dynamically as following style/order **Controller> action**.

ex:

`class Office::MeetingController < ApplicationController
    def today
    ...
    end
    def yesterday
    ...
    end
end`

I want to display the title dynamically (i.e dynamically put the title on the page), like

today page title => Office> Meeting> Today
yesterday page title => Office> Meeting> Yesterday

I feel lazy to use the title tag. ;)

thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use two ways:

1 Set it in your layout file:

```
<title>
  <%= controller.controller_name %> > <%= controller.action_name %>
</title>
```

2 You can use `yield` in your layout:

```
<title>
  <%= yield :title || "No title" %>
</title>
```

and then in your views you can call `content_for`

```
<%= content_for :title do %>
   <%= controller.controller_name %> > <%= controller.action_name %>
<% end %>
```

And you can watch this screencast http://railscasts.com/episodes/30-pretty-page-title